# SUM 2 Field from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql query like this :

```
SELECT SUM(bills.Amount) AS AmountExpense, SUM(assets.Amount) as AmountIncome 
FROM bills, assets where bills.UserId = 11 and assets.UserId =11
```

Sample Bills table

```
id  payee  description  UserId          Amount 
1  john   advance          11           15.0         
2  dave   request          2            13.0 
3  er     request          11           12.0
```

Sample assets table

```
id  payee  description  UserId          Amount 
1  john   advance          11           40.2        
2  dave   request          2            13.0
3  ww     request          11           14.00
```

I have a problem with AmountExpense, the record SUM record multiple time. I have successed with Amount Income. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add some sample data? Also add how these two tables are related to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have most likely more than one row per user on one or both of those tables. You'll need to join them after performing the aggregation. Also, please don't use old style non ANSI implicit joins:

```
SELECT AmountExpense, AmountIncome
FROM (  SELECT  UserId, 
                SUM(Amount) AS AmountExpense
        FROM bills
        GROUP BY UserId) AS b
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  UserId,
                    SUM(Amount) AmountIncome
            FROM assets
            GROUP BY UserId) AS a
    ON b.UserId = a.UserId
WHERE b.UserId = 11
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility that users can be in either table, but not the other, then you want the equivalent of a `full outer join`.  MySQL doesn't support that syntax, but it does support this:

```
select userid, sum(amountexpense) as amountexpense, sum(amountincome) as amountincome
from (select userid, amount as amountexpense, null as amountincome
      from bills
      union all
      select userid, null, amount as amountincome
      from assets
     ) ba
group by userid;
```